# SQL Server Connection with Python PYMSSQL active directory authentication

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, windows-authentication, python-3.8, pymssql

I am trying to connect SQL Server using pymssql package with active directory authentication.   Below is the code.

```py
db = pymssql.connect(server=url, user=r'Domain\user', password=password, database=database)
cursor = db.cursor()
```

But it fails with below error:

> Error (18452, b'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed ()\n')

Python version: Python 3.8.6
PYMSSQL version: pymssql 2.1.5

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that will work. Try it like this.

```
# connect to SQL Server
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

driver= '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=your_server_name;'
    r'DATABASE=your_db_name;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Employee')

# print contents of table
for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

Answer (score 0):

For most client libraries you can't specify the username/password with Windows Integrated Auth.  It just connects as the identity of the current process.

To do otherwise would require the driver to implement (or us a library that implements) the NTLM or Kerberos authentication protocols, and AFAIK only the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server does that.